# Rails not finding controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes

So, I have the following link-to:

```
 <%= link_to(outing_add_guests_path, :class => 'modal') do %>
 <div id="notImportant"></div>
 <% end %>
```

When I click on it, Rails tells me that

```
No route matches {:controller=>"outings", :action=>"add_guests"}
```

However, here's my routes file:

```
resources :outings do
  get "/add_guests" => "outings#add_guests"
  post "/add_guests" => "outings#add_guests"
  delete "/remove_guests" => "outings#remove_guests"
end
```

and the corresponding action from my Outings Controller:

```
def add_guests
    @outing_guest = OutingGuest.new(:outing_id => params[:outing_id])
    @outing_guest.user_id = params[:user_id]
    if @outing_guest.save
        flash[:notice] = "Guest added successfully"
        redirect_to({ :action => 'outing', :id => params[:outing_id] })
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Guest could not be added"
        redirect_to({ :action => 'outing', :id => params[:outing_id] })
    end
end
```

Is there any reason Rails would be unable to detect my controller or its actions?

EDIT: Here's part of the results from rake routes

```
            outing_add_guests GET    /outings/:outing_id/add_guests(.:format)                outings#add_guests
                              POST   /outings/:outing_id/add_guests(.:format)                outings#add_guests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice your `link_to` is not consistent with the other routes

```
outing_add_guests_path
outings_add_guests_path
```

Did you do `rake routes` to verify that `outing_add_guests_path` exists?

EDIT:

Your `rake routes` shows you need an `outing_id` so your routes aren't setup right (at least not for the POST). I'd fix them the way @RyanBigg is suggesting.

Comment: I tried change it to outings_add_guests_path, but it said the method was undefined. I've added my rakes route to up above.

Comment: Yeah, that was in fact the problem. This is a view for a new Outing, but the Add Guests was written to add guests to an existing outing, so it requires an outing_id.

Answer (score 1):

You should be defining these routes using the `collection` method:

```
resources :outings do
  collection do
    get :add_guests
    post :add_guests
    delete :remove_guests
  end
end
```

What this will do is define new routes for the specified actions, as well as automatically defining the routing helpers for those routes. For more information please read the [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).